# How to fix an error with the quickstart tutorial for pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to follow the tutorial on pytorch [HERE](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html), but there seems to be a problem. I have created a custom dataloader named `training_data` that returns an object as required [HERE](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) which is a dictionary

```
{"image": image, "label": label}
```

where `image` is a tensor and `label` is a string. I then follow the tutorial and create a `DataLoader` as follows:

```
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=batch_size)
```

and use that `DataLoader` in the method `train`:

```
def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

However, when I call the training method for a batch

```
train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_network.py", line 110, in <module>
    train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
  File "train_network.py", line 76, in train
    X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to'
```

as `y` is a string with the content `label`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `y` should be a torch tensor.

Comment: According to the documentation it is a label. So how do I create a tensor from a label string?

Comment: Is using something like `torch.tensor([0]]` and `torch.tensor([1])` the correct way for the two labels that I have?

Comment: Depends on the data and type of problem. For example, if you are trying to classify from among N classes, a typical representation is to assign each label to an integer from 0 to N-1, and use that to train the model. Another common way is to use a one-hot encoding.

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: Does not work. I still get the same error message. The value `y` is ALWAYS a string with content `label`. Something seems to be very wrong in the tutorial. It seems it is taking just the KEY from `{"image": image, "label": label}`. So the example of the data set maybe is incorrect?

Comment: Are you also using Fashion MNIST? The labels should be integers already if you are downloading using torchvision.

Comment: No, I am trying to use my own dataset

Comment: Then that's the issue, the tutorial uses a dataset where the labels are already integers. If that is not the case for your dataset, you need to convert it yourself.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet where and how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232728/discussion-between-alex-and-gooddeeds).

Answer (score 1):

Your labels `y` need to be torch tensors. Since you currently have strings, and assuming you are doing classification among `n` classes, you can simply map them using a list. For example, with three classes, inside the `__init__` of your `Dataset` class:

```
self.label_names = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
```

Then, in `__getitem__`, you could add:

```
label = torch.tensor(label_names.index(label))
```

where `label` previously stored a string.

Comment: @Alex What's the error? At least, it should not be the same issue.

Comment: Same issue. But when my dataset returns a tuple `spec[0], label` instead of `{"image": spec[0], "label": label}` (with `label` an integer), then I do not get the error anymore

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a valid type for your dataset to return (though to be fair the more common practice is to have your dataset's `__getitem__` method return `data`,`label` as two separate tensors.)

In any case, when your dataset `__getitem__` method returns an object of type dict, the [`collate_fn`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py) of pytorch returns a dict as well, with the same keys. Your issue is that you are trying to move the key (a string), rather than the value (a tensor) to the GPU.

Instead do:

```
for batch, datum in enumerate(dataloader):
   X = datum["image"].to(device)
   y = datum["label"].to(device)
   ...
```

However, as noted by @GoodDeeds, I am fairly confident that you need to convert from string labels to integer-type labels for classification (via one-hot encoding as detailed in that answer).

```
# from GoodDeeds answer, I include to condense both relevant changes into one answer
self.label_names = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
label = torch.tensor(label_names.index(label)) # in __getitem__ method
```

If you don't want to edit the dataset at all you could define a custom `collate_fn` for your dataloader that replaces string class names with integers, or else perform this type conversion after loading the data batch (not recommended).